# php for loop and storing in to arrays

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to pass some values from javascript to a php file, thru ajax request and store each result(from for loop) in to an array using php.

```
queryData={"data":{"data_string":{"data":"medicine","default_field":"Content"}}}
testArgument=0;

$.ajax({
    url:"test/queryManipulate.php",
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {field : queryData, start : testArgument},
    success:function(jsonQuery)
    {
       alert(jsonQuery);
    }
});


<?php

    $i=0;
for ($from = 0; $from <= 50; $from+=10)
{
$object=json_decode($_POST["field"]); 
$object->from=$from; 
$object=json_encode($object);
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:9200/algotree//_search");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $object);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$test= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$newArray[$i]= $test;
$i++;
echo $newArray[2];
}
?>
```

MY for loop doesn't work. Am I using it the right way and also how do I store each result in to an array in php?

Comment: why don't you try using json_decode? that will convert your json automatically into an array... what I see on your example is that you're not passing the `start` value on the request, so maybe that is your problem

Comment: Im passing start value at request inside data field.. I anna store results in to separatearray..

Comment: what is the equivalent of javascript for loop in php?? like arrayname[i]=result.. i++;

Comment: _"My for loop doesn't work."_ - In what sense? Does nothing, does something but not the right thing, gives errors, or...?

Comment: Did you mean to do `$from += 10`?

Comment: yes..that was a typo...thats nt the issue.. I want to store the result in to an array..it will only produce the first result..instead of five different result..

Comment: Ive edited my question to get a better understanding... this gives me an error undefined offset

Comment: Use `var_dump` and stop guessing

Answer (score 0):

The first loop should be

```
    <?php
        for($from = $_POST["start"]; $from<50;$from+=10)
        {
             // other code
        }
```

Note the $from += 10 not $from+10.

Comment: that was a typo.. thats not the issue..the issue is with storing each value in to  an array..

Comment: So what error are you getting? If you do a var_dump($i) is it actually incrementing throughout the loop. Need some more info of what you have tried I think.

Comment: if I try to echo var_dump($i), it shows error ( ! ) Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in test\queryManipulate.php on line 10 and prints int 0 to 4 five times..

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, before converting to json string ,we have to format data  using array and objects like ,

```
data_string  = new Object();
data = new Array();

data_string[data] = "medicine";
data_string[default_field] = "Content";

data.push(data_string);
```

then encode the data to json , will results like

```
{"data":{"data_string":{"data":"medicine","default_field":"Content"}}}
```

then pass to php file through ajax  and then decode json using

`json_encode(data);` in php

then do further process..